# Probability of picking a face card on the 7th try

Tags: probability

Given a standard deck, and drawing 10 cards at random from that deck, what is the probability of picking a face card (JQK) on the 7th draw? I'm not sure what distribution this is. I'm not sure because I can't tell from the problem if the 7th draw is the first face card to be drawn (in which case it is geometric) or if the number of the draw actually matters (like if it would occur with equal probability on the 3rd draw, in which i think it is binomial distribution). Is this a legitimate issue?

Comment: Nothing special about the $7^{th}$ draw....there are $12$ face cards, so the answer is $\frac {12}{52}$.

Comment: As you say, it's different if the problem specifies that the first six draws were non-face cards.  But that's quite a stretch from the given statement.  Of course, you could just compute that probability as well.  Note:  it is not geometric unless you are replacing the cards each time.  The more you draw non-face cards, the more likely it is that the next one will be a face card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that you draw without replacement and that the problem is asking for the probability that the $7^{th}$ card is the first face card you see:

There are $12$ face cards and $40$ non-face cards in an ordinary deck.  It follows that the probability that the first is a non-face card is $\frac {40}{52}$.  Conditioned on that, the probability that the second is also a non-face card is $\frac {39}{51}$.  Continuing in this way we see that the answer we want is $$\frac {40}{52}\times \frac {39}{51}\times \frac {38}{50}\times \frac {37}{49}\times \frac {36}{48}\times \frac {35}{47}\times \frac {12}{46}\sim 0.049184151$$

Note:  just to compare, the probability that the $7^{th}$ is a face card (with no condition on the first six) is just $\frac {12}{52}\sim 0.230769231$.